# iMacros - Extract Text & Set As VAR

Tags: string, random, imacros

I used iMacros to make a script. However, I have an issue with the `!EXTRACT` option. I try extract the text from the URL `http://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=12&digits=on&upperalpha=on&unique=on&format=plain&rnd=new`.

and set it as a variable (I believe it's `{{!EXTRACT}})` so it can be used later in the macro.

I tried to use an extract script made by someone else, but get `#EANF#` when extracting; I tried to extract using `HTML` and `all text on page`.

I was wondering if anybody can help me / guide me in the right direction of extracting all the 12 characters from here, setting it as a variable and allowing me to use it later in the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **TXT** option for extract, here is a walk through of a very simple macro.

### Example

Go to the random string website:

```
URL GOTO=http://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=12&digits=on&upperalpha=on&unique=on&format=plain&rnd=new
```

Extract all the text from the first "pre" tag on the page, the value is placed in the EXTRACT variable:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Show the extracted string to the user in a prompt, reference the value using {{!*var_name*}}

```
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```